# .net 5 ClickOnce FTP no longer an option?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce, .net-5

So I used to use an FTP path in the form of ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/Folder/ with click once and on .NET framework this was working fine however I recently moved over to .NET 5 in order to prepare for the move to .NET Maui in the future. and so far the biggest problem I'm having is there seems to be no FTP publish support anymore. Publish App=>new publish profile=>Folder=>ClickOnce. And here it asks for a Publish Location. It shows only examples for local files/ UNC Paths. when I put my ftp path in there I receive the following message invalid path. the UNC path should be of form \server\share. Are FTP paths no longer acceptable for Click once publishing?

Comment: Maybe you can post a comment on this blog. [`Announcing .NET 5.0 RC 2`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-rc-2/)

Comment: @KyleWang Comments are closed for that article sadly :/ i did create an issue with visual studio about it. and found several existing issues... it seems the click once wizard was not thoroughly tested so just about every aspect of it has some sort of bug... really sucks becouse the wizard itself looks like it would be a nice upgrade

Comment: I tested in my side and it should be a bug, try to use your own account to report another problem on [Developer Community .NET](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=61)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When transitioning from .NET Framework to .NET 5 it seems we are moving forward with the .NET 3 click once which does not support the FTP option. Microsoft confirmed this has been removed for .NET 3 and 5 and is not a bug.